# Как указать стиль для <option selected>?

Tags: css

Как в CSS указать стиль для `<option selected>`? Возможно ли это без использования JS?

```
<select>
   <option value="t1">Чебурашка</option>
   <option selected value="t2">Крыса Лариса</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно. CSS2 позволяет делать выборку по [атрибутам тегов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). Для того чтобы указать на наличие атрибута используется селектор вида `tag[attribute]`.

Ваш код может выглядеть так:

```css
option[selected] {
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltfhgtbz/1/).

**Дополнение**:

Кроссбраузерная стилизация `select`'ов является достаточно сложной задачей. В большинстве случае имеет смысл использовать специальные JavaScript библиотеки, которые фактически заменяют `select` на набор `div`'ов. Таких библиотек очень много. Например, [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Comment: упс – http://joxi.ru/DmBEQoEu6zbLrP

Comment: @korytoff, обновил fiddle

Comment: ну в современных браузерах (в последних версиях) наверно везде будет норм работать (без js)?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev все равно то же самое. Не забывайте, что есть еще Linux, Mac OS, Android, iOs и т.к.

Comment: @VitalikZ, зависит от стилей и, как указал **korytoff**, могут быть проблемы с некоторыми системами. Если цель, охватить максимальное количество браузеров -- проще использовать JS.

Answer (score 1):

Так должно работать:

```
option:checked { color: green; }
```

Comment: Это не `checkbox`

Comment: Дмитрий, можете проверить и убедиться, что это рабочий вариант:
http://jsfiddle.net/bjjd34ns/
Тут вопрос в том, для какой задачи это реально нужно.
option:checked - позволяет менять стили последенго выбранного элемента, что необходимо в некоторых случаях, чтобы пользователь мог видеть, какой элемент последний был выбран.

Comment: ваш fiddle не работает в FireFox

Comment: Если что, я не минусовал ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev у меня в Opera 31 оба варианта работают одинаково: стили у элемента присутствуют, но визуально не применяются.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. В Хроме все работает, в FF действительно нет. Учту на будущее. Про минусы - не страшно, если заслуженно, и не важно, кто его поставил =)

Comment: @Aries ваше решение выручит тех, кому нужно стилизовать выбранный элемент в `select` с атрибутом `size` больше 1. Поэтому однозначно +1

Answer (score 1):

У выпадающих списков ограниченные возможности по стилизации + на каждой платформе они имеют свой внешний вид. Рекомендую либо использовать JS библиотеки либо написать что нибудь свое.

### Дополнение

Я имел ввиду не конкретную библиотеку, а использование готового решения в принципе. Список таких библиотек велик. Мои любимые это:

1. [Bootstrap Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)
2. [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: Тащить в проект bootstrap только для кастомизации `select` как-то избыточно.

Comment: Ну так напишите свой, тут вообще ничего сложного. Скрываете оригинал, добавляете блочные элементы и вешаете на все эвенты. Bootstrap как пример, есть большое кол-во кастомных селектов

Comment: А зачем писать велосипед, если существует масса готовых решений без bootstrap. Например http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, ну во-первых я имел ввиду как раз большее кол-во готовых решений, а во-вторых нужно писать свои велосипеды, иначе программирование и разработка как таковые скоро вымрет и останутся только танцы с бубном дабы прикрутить ненужную тяжелую библиотеку. Я люблю велосипеды ;)

Comment: А я люблю делать Pull Request'ы в готовые решения ;-)